# How can I redirect to any screen of flutter app with url?

Tags: flutter, dart

In one screen of my app there is sharing button.I want after pressing this button,app to send a url to any platform that user had chosen.Whenever this link is pressed,the user is redirected to the same screen of app.[image]
as it shown on this image,we send a link

[image: you can see what I want to do]

I know that I will use some package for sending url.But I can not understand from url how can I redirect to particular screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links)

When your app starts, you'll be able to tell if the app was started using a dynamic link.  If it was you can route to whatever screen you want based on what the URL was. Using a package like [go_router](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router) for your routing might be helpful too.

Comment: Thank you so much sir .I will try it now and inform you it works or not